# Can't draw array of markers from array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to place markers on a map given the data in an array of objects. Using the sample code from the Google Maps API documentation I can place a single marker but once I get to the markers I actually want to place nothing happens. I can see the markers data using console.log() but the markers won't be placed on the map.

The only error I'm getting is from call the script before the Google Maps API. Otherwise everything else seems to be fine (the map loads).

All files are run using file://.

I'm probably missing something blindingly obvious. I just started learning JavaScript a few days ago and the Maps API this morning.

Code building the map.

```
  var myLatLng = {lat: 36.602414870756, lng: -105.08904326937};

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: 'hybrid',     //'satellite' with labels
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    rotateControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: false,
    center: myLatLng
  };
  var globalMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
```

Source array.

```
var staffedCamps = [
...,
{
  id: 5,
  Name: "Black Mountain",
  lat: -105.0931424,
  long: 36.44229773,
  UTM_E: 491633.5115,
  UTM_N: 4033044.5622,
  Type: "Staff"
},
...,
```

Code building the array of markers.

```
var markerData = new Array()
for (let newMark = 0; newMark < staffedCamps.length; newMark++) {
  var cMark = staffedCamps[newMark];
  markerData.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat:cMark.lat, lng:cMark.long},
    map: globalMap,
    title: cMark.Name,
    label: cMark.Name
  }));
console.log(markerData)
```

HTML

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script defer src="main.js" onload="initMap()"></script>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=some_api_key&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: If you drill down into one of the markers in the console does it have a map object set? How near are these camps to your initial centre (will zooming out reveal them)?

Comment: The code seems fine (though we haven't seen what's in main.js, or your initMap function) Looks to me like you've got the lat and long in your data the wrong way round compared to the centre of your map. Pretty sure latitude of -105 is not on the map :)

Comment: @kevmc I think your right about having the lat long wrong way around. I'll give it a swing this evening when I'm home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an example to put several markers, i use this `new google.maps.Marker`  for create many markers

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.38, 2.18);
  var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.37, 2.17);

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
  var array = [{
      draggable: true,
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: "Your location"
    },
    {
      draggable: true,
      position: myLatlng2,
      map: map,
      title: "Your location"
    }
  ]

  markerNow();

  function markerNow() {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker(array[i]);
    }
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCK3ulYYM8GCwK-_HlZVNKvkgp-zvEebUM&"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you x-rw. This code helps clean things up. @kevmc found the issue though.